# Exception when connecting to SFTP server using WinSCP C# code - PrivateKeyPassphrase is set, but not SshPrivateKeyPath and TlsClientCertificatePath

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I am building an application which uses C# code to connect to an SFP server. The other party says that they do not provide key files. When connecting to their SFTP server via FileZilla only using host + user + passphrase + port, I successfully connect (after accepting the host key that appears on the pop up window).

However when running the code I keep getting the below exception:

> SessionOptions.PrivateKeyPassphrase is set, but neither SessionOptions.SshPrivateKeyPath nor SessionOptions.TlsClientCertificatePath is set.

I am using `WinSCP.SessionOptions` to build the connection.

How can establish a connection without having to point to a .ppk file as FileZilla does?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not connecting with the user and *passphrase*, but with a *password*.

So you need to set [`SessionOptions.Password` property](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#password), not `SessionOptions.PrivateKeyPassphrase`.

---

The [*passphrase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passphrase) is indeed used in combination with private keys only.